# Compiling ImGui in C++

Tags: c++, imgui

On https://github.com/ocornut/imgui it says: `No specific build process is required. You can add the .cpp files to your existing project.` I tried this using Code Blocks with the relevant `.cpp` files, however it gives me about 500+ `Undefined Reference to ... errors`. The first beginning in `imgui.cpp` being `` |1994|undefined reference to `ImGui::InputText(char const*, char*, unsigned long, int, int (*)(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData*), void*)' ``. This is the following code I tried.

```
#include "imgui.h"



int main()
{

    bool my_tool_active = true;
    float my_color = 0.5;


    // Create a window called "My First Tool", with a menu bar.
    ImGui::Begin("My First Tool", &my_tool_active, ImGuiWindowFlags_MenuBar);
    if (ImGui::BeginMenuBar())
    {
        if (ImGui::BeginMenu("File"))
        {
            if (ImGui::MenuItem("Open..", "Ctrl+O")) { /* Do stuff */ }
            if (ImGui::MenuItem("Save", "Ctrl+S"))   { /* Do stuff */ }
            if (ImGui::MenuItem("Close", "Ctrl+W"))  { my_tool_active = false; }
            ImGui::EndMenu();
        }
        ImGui::EndMenuBar();
    }

    // Edit a color (stored as ~4 floats)
    ImGui::ColorEdit4("Color", &my_color);

    // Plot some values
    const float my_values[] = { 0.2f, 0.1f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 2.2f };
    ImGui::PlotLines("Frame Times", my_values, IM_ARRAYSIZE(my_values));

    // Display contents in a scrolling region
    ImGui::TextColored(ImVec4(1,1,0,1), "Important Stuff");
    ImGui::BeginChild("Scrolling");
    for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
        ImGui::Text("%04d: Some text", n);
    ImGui::EndChild();
    ImGui::End();


    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing? I can't find any linker commands on the webpage which (in my experience "undefined reference to..." is usually a result of missing linker options)

Comment: `(in my experience "undefined reference to..." is usually a result of missing linker options`  tells you that the linker does not find the definitions for the used declarations in the header files. In your case, you most certainly don't include the relevant `cpp` files of imgui correctly in your project (you probably just copied them to your project directory but didn't add them to the project to be compiled).

Comment: I copied the ```.cpp``` and ```.h``` files that the website says to use, and put them in my project folder where I added them to my ```codeblocks``` project

Comment: `ImGui::InputText` is defined in imgui_widgets.cpp (which is one of the files you are supposed to add) so you must have made a mistake somewhere. The web site says add **all** the files in the root folder, did you do that?

Comment: Apparently not! Thanks for pointing that out. The file is in the directory but somehow I missed adding the ```imgui_widgets.cpp``` to my project in codeblocks. The compilation works now, which is great, however the sample code they published doesn't work. ```Segmentation fault (core dumped)```

Comment: @GgsgnHdjwngnf Sorry but I've no experience with that. Feel free to ask a new question if you can't get it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

i have some problems compiling imgui but once you get it it's not that complicated.

first you need to understand what kind of setup you need, in my case i use gnome with wayland on gentoo linux, so i wanted to use imgui with opengl and glfw, so by the getting started documentation at https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/wiki/Getting-Started i understood that i need to include the following `backends/imgui_impl_glfw.h` and `backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.h`.

then i literally just copied one of the examples to get it to work, just changed the main function to imgui_main to run it manually on my original cpp file:

```
#include "my_imgui.h"

// Dear ImGui: standalone example application for GLFW + OpenGL 3, using programmable pipeline
// (GLFW is a cross-platform general purpose library for handling windows, inputs, OpenGL/Vulkan/Metal graphics context creation, etc.)

// Learn about Dear ImGui:
// - FAQ                  https://dearimgui.com/faq
// - Getting Started      https://dearimgui.com/getting-started
// - Documentation        https://dearimgui.com/docs (same as your local docs/ folder).
// - Introduction, links and more at the top of imgui.cpp

#include "imgui.h"
#include "backends/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include <cstdio>
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#if defined(IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_ES2)
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#endif
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // Will drag system OpenGL headers

// [Win32] Our example includes a copy of glfw3.lib pre-compiled with VS2010 to maximize ease of testing and compatibility with old VS compilers.
// To link with VS2010-era libraries, VS2015+ requires linking with legacy_stdio_definitions.lib, which we do using this pragma.
// Your own project should not be affected, as you are likely to link with a newer binary of GLFW that is adequate for your version of Visual Studio.
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900) && !defined(IMGUI_DISABLE_WIN32_FUNCTIONS)
#pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions")
#endif

// This example can also compile and run with Emscripten! See 'Makefile.emscripten' for details.
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include "../libs/emscripten/emscripten_mainloop_stub.h"
#endif

static void glfw_error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GLFW Error %d: %s\n", error, description);
}

// Main code
int imgui_main(int, char**)
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        return 1;

    // Decide GL+GLSL versions
#if defined(IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_ES2)
    // GL ES 2.0 + GLSL 100
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 100";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
    // GL 3.2 + GLSL 150
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 150";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // Required on Mac
#else
    // GL 3.0 + GLSL 130
    const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // 3.2+ only
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);            // 3.0+ only
#endif

    // Create window with graphics context
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Dear ImGui GLFW+OpenGL3 example", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr)
        return 1;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1); // Enable vsync

    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;     // Enable Keyboard Controls
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableGamepad;      // Enable Gamepad Controls

    // Setup Dear ImGui style
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
    //ImGui::StyleColorsLight();

    // Setup Platform/Renderer backends
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, true);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init(glsl_version);

    // Load Fonts
    // - If no fonts are loaded, dear imgui will use the default font. You can also load multiple fonts and use ImGui::PushFont()/PopFont() to select them.
    // - AddFontFromFileTTF() will return the ImFont* so you can store it if you need to select the font among multiple.
    // - If the file cannot be loaded, the function will return a nullptr. Please handle those errors in your application (e.g. use an assertion, or display an error and quit).
    // - The fonts will be rasterized at a given size (w/ oversampling) and stored into a texture when calling ImFontAtlas::Build()/GetTexDataAsXXXX(), which ImGui_ImplXXXX_NewFrame below will call.
    // - Use '#define IMGUI_ENABLE_FREETYPE' in your imconfig file to use Freetype for higher quality font rendering.
    // - Read 'docs/FONTS.md' for more instructions and details.
    // - Remember that in C/C++ if you want to include a backslash \ in a string literal you need to write a double backslash \\ !
    // - Our Emscripten build process allows embedding fonts to be accessible at runtime from the "fonts/" folder. See Makefile.emscripten for details.
    //io.Fonts->AddFontDefault();
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\segoeui.ttf", 18.0f);
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../misc/fonts/DroidSans.ttf", 16.0f);
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../misc/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf", 16.0f);
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../misc/fonts/Cousine-Regular.ttf", 15.0f);
    //ImFont* font = io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ArialUni.ttf", 18.0f, nullptr, io.Fonts->GetGlyphRangesJapanese());
    //IM_ASSERT(font != nullptr);

    // Our state
    bool show_demo_window = true;
    bool show_another_window = false;
    ImVec4 clear_color = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);

    // Main loop
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    // For an Emscripten build we are disabling file-system access, so let's not attempt to do a fopen() of the imgui.ini file.
    // You may manually call LoadIniSettingsFromMemory() to load settings from your own storage.
    io.IniFilename = nullptr;
    EMSCRIPTEN_MAINLOOP_BEGIN
#else
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
#endif
    {
        // Poll and handle events (inputs, window resize, etc.)
        // You can read the io.WantCaptureMouse, io.WantCaptureKeyboard flags to tell if dear imgui wants to use your inputs.
        // - When io.WantCaptureMouse is true, do not dispatch mouse input data to your main application, or clear/overwrite your copy of the mouse data.
        // - When io.WantCaptureKeyboard is true, do not dispatch keyboard input data to your main application, or clear/overwrite your copy of the keyboard data.
        // Generally you may always pass all inputs to dear imgui, and hide them from your application based on those two flags.
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Start the Dear ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        // 1. Show the big demo window (Most of the sample code is in ImGui::ShowDemoWindow()! You can browse its code to learn more about Dear ImGui!).
        if (show_demo_window)
            ImGui::ShowDemoWindow(&show_demo_window);

        // 2. Show a simple window that we create ourselves. We use a Begin/End pair to create a named window.
        {
            static float f = 0.0f;
            static int counter = 0;

            ImGui::Begin("Hello, world!");                          // Create a window called "Hello, world!" and append into it.

            ImGui::Text("This is some useful text.");               // Display some text (you can use a format strings too)
            ImGui::Checkbox("Demo Window", &show_demo_window);      // Edit bools storing our window open/close state
            ImGui::Checkbox("Another Window", &show_another_window);

            ImGui::SliderFloat("float", &f, 0.0f, 1.0f);            // Edit 1 float using a slider from 0.0f to 1.0f
            ImGui::ColorEdit3("clear color", (float*)&clear_color); // Edit 3 floats representing a color

            if (ImGui::Button("Button"))                            // Buttons return true when clicked (most widgets return true when edited/activated)
                counter++;
            ImGui::SameLine();
            ImGui::Text("counter = %d", counter);

            ImGui::Text("Application average %.3f ms/frame (%.1f FPS)", 1000.0f / io.Framerate, io.Framerate);
            ImGui::End();
        }

        // 3. Show another simple window.
        if (show_another_window)
        {
            ImGui::Begin("Another Window", &show_another_window);   // Pass a pointer to our bool variable (the window will have a closing button that will clear the bool when clicked)
            ImGui::Text("Hello from another window!");
            if (ImGui::Button("Close Me"))
                show_another_window = false;
            ImGui::End();
        }

        // Rendering
        ImGui::Render();
        int display_w, display_h;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &display_w, &display_h);
        glViewport(0, 0, display_w, display_h);
        glClearColor(clear_color.x * clear_color.w, clear_color.y * clear_color.w, clear_color.z * clear_color.w, clear_color.w);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    EMSCRIPTEN_MAINLOOP_END;
#endif

    // Cleanup
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

so if i have this example written to `features/imgui/my_imgui.cpp`, i also have `my_imgui.h` (latest on i will convert it to classes, for now it's empty.

i placed the external imgui library at `PROJECT_SRC/extern/imgui`

and now the `CMakeList.txt`

again you can do it as you want, i'm new to `CMakeList.txt` there might be better ways, but it's clean and it's working :)

so i created an option that is enabled by default for `imgui`:

```
option(F_IMGUI "imgui Support" ON)
```

in my make cmakelists file i find the opengl and glfw3 packages, and add the `extern/imgui` to the include directories:

```
if (F_IMGUI)

    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)


    find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui)
endif()
```

and in the cmakelists file inside `src` directory, i'm linking the opengl and glfw libraries and adding the relevant imgui source files:

```
if (F_IMGUI)
    target_link_libraries(tux_music_studio_server_cpp PRIVATE
            OpenGL::GL)
    target_link_libraries(tux_music_studio_server_cpp PRIVATE
            glfw)

    target_sources(tux_music_studio_server_cpp PRIVATE
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui/imgui.cpp
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp
    )

    target_sources(tux_music_studio_server_cpp PRIVATE
            features/imgui/my_imgui.cpp
            features/imgui/my_imgui.h
    )



endif()
```

now if you get `undefined reference` to an imgui function, just grep the imgui source dir for that function definition and add that to the compilation too.

if you  get segmentation fault, as long as you followed their getting started guide properly, i would try a different option, vulkan instead of opengl, or any other options that are available (i'm not really sure on what OS you're on).

in my example i use gtx3060 with wayland, so i don't really have much options besides opengl and glfw with imgui, but if in my case it would cause a segmentation fault as well, than i would create a simple hello world example of each technology individually, in this case, i will try to compile and run an hello world example for opengl, and glfw individually, maybe one of them will segfault, so at least i'll have more information and move on from there.

i really love imgui, i'm sure you'd too, have fun.